# /tools/suggested edits doesn't show mod diamonds:

Tags: bug, 10k-tools

> [image]

RolandiXor and Robert Cartaino should have diamonds, but they don't.

This is on [elementary OS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/tools/suggested-edits).